# Reset IIS 7.5 from remote machine

Tags: iis-7

How to reset IIS 7 on multiple Windows Server 2008 server machines from remote computer using a vbscript.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:
 iisreset.exe [computername]

Otherwise, it depends if you are looking to recycle just worker processes, or what? You could use SCM to Start and Stop w3SVC, or FTP. Or use AHADMIN to recycle individual Application Pools.